# Add quotation marks to each word in a file

Tags: linux, bash, list, words

I have some words separated by commas in a file, such as below:

```
variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4
```

What's the easiest way to use BASH for adding quotation marks to each word?

The end result should look like:

```
"variable1", "variable2", "variable3", "variable4"
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please give some example of things you've tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply with **`sed`**:

```
sed 's/[^[:space:],]\+/"&"/g' file
```

The output:

```
"variable1", "variable2", "variable3", "variable4"
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with parameter expansion

```
str="variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4"
str2=\""${str//, /\", \"}"\"

echo "$str2"
```

however to have a csv format, double quotes should be just before the comma without space, the reason of double quotes may be to allow `,` inside a field but if field already contains a comma the quoting must be done before.