# Add quotation marks to each var in a txt file

Tags: bash, macos

Similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152407/add-quotation-marks-to-each-word-in-a-file), I would like to have double quotes around each variable (which are sometimes strings, sometimes numbers) separated by commas in a file without spaces, such as below:

```
variable1,12345,variable2,AA3
```

What's the easiest way to use BASH (on macOS 10.14.6) for adding quotation marks to each word?

The end result should look like:

```
"variable1","12345","variable2","AA3"
```

Comment: Why don't you use any of the answers to your linked question?

Comment: Because I do not know ‘sed’ or alike to do the necessary adjustments to my specific case (no spaces between commas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'sed' to insert '"' at the start of the line, end of line, and replace every '.' with '","'.

```
sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' -e 's/,/","/g'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using single `sed` command:

```
s='variable1,12345,variable2,AA3'
sed -E 's/[^,]+/"&"/g' <<< "$s"
```

```
"variable1","12345","variable2","AA3"
```